# Device shadow state not changes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Trying to create aws-iot device by using [manual](https://hub.packtpub.com/build-an-iot-application-with-aws-iot-tutorial/). I did all required settings while creating  `Pi3-DHT11-Node device`. Simplified code below:

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk'); 
const NODE_ID = 'Pi3-DHT11-Noded'; 
const INIT_DELAY = 15; 
const TAG = '[' + NODE_ID + '] >>>>>>>>> '; 

var thingShadow = awsIot.thingShadow({ 
  keyPath: './certs_p/fea2f8efae7-private.pem.key', 
  certPath: './certs_p/fea2f8efae7-certificate.pem.crt', 
  caPath: './certs_p/AmazonRootCA1.pem', 
  clientId: NODE_ID, 
  host: 'a3cnel9blokzm0-ats.iot.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com',
  port: 8883, 
  region: 'eu-west-3', 
  debug: true, // optional to see logs on console 
}); 

thingShadow.on('connect', function() { 
  console.log(TAG, 'Connected.'); 
  thingShadow.register(NODE_ID, {}, function() { 
    console.log(TAG, 'Registered.'); 
    console.log(TAG, 'Reading data in ' + INIT_DELAY + ' seconds.'); 
    setTimeout(sendData, INIT_DELAY * 1000); // wait for `INIT_DELAY` seconds before reading the first record 
  }); 
}); 

function sendData() { 
  var DHT11State = { 
    "state": { 
      "desired": 
        { 
        "temp": 20, 
        "humd": 33 
        }
    } 
  }; 

  var clientTokenUpdate = thingShadow.update(NODE_ID, DHT11State); 
  if (clientTokenUpdate === null) { 
    console.log(TAG, 'Shadow update failed, operation still in progress'); 
  } else { 
    console.log(TAG, 'Shadow update success.'); 
  } 

  // keep sending the data every 30 seconds 
  console.log(TAG, 'Reading data again in 30 seconds.'); 
  setTimeout(sendData, 30000); // 30,000 ms => 30 seconds 
}
```

[image]

Script is working fine, but this does not change shadow state. Why? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you do not have the device setup to sync the shadow to the cloud.

Follow the steps in this part of the tutorial, and ensure that you click on "Sync to the Cloud" as per Step 2, then redeploy your Greengrass Group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/comms-enabled.html

Comment: I'm using IoT core service and not something related to Greengrass. I can't find any selection "Sync to the Cloud".

Comment: ah my bad! I was working in GG when I saw this question. OK... have you tried subscribing to the shadow topics in the AWS console to see if your messages are being received? subscribe to `$aws/things/Pi3-DHT11-Noded/shadow/#` and see if you see any messages. I suspect it's not getting there. do you see any debug from your application which suggests comms to AWS are ok?

Comment: I tried to subscribe to`$aws/things/Pi3-DHT11-Noded/shadow/#` in Test section of AWS IoT console. And I see messages from my device there.

Comment: have a look on the `rejected` topic: `$aws/things/Pi3-DHT11-Noded/shadow/update/rejected` .. if there is something wrong with your shadow, aws iot will reject it with the reason posted on this topic.